# A probable inspiring proof to Poincare lemma

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

Poincare lemma says if a smooth $p$-form $\omega$ is closed, then $\omega$ must be exact.

Let's put it in another way, it says the solution of $d\omega=0$ is $\omega=d\eta$ for some $(p-1)$-form $\eta$

So my idea is trying to apply Frobenius theorem to provide solution to differential equations? But I don't know How.

Comment: @Schuchang Zhang are you aware of the literature by Olver, or the texts on Exterior Differential Systems? I think these put considerable effort into this type of endeavor. So, yes, you can understand much about DEs by reformulating them as differential forms and then using Frob. theorem in that context. After all, Frob. theorem is just a generalization of the fundamental existence theorem of ODEs... well, this is a poor recollection of what I read in Olver...

Comment: Thanks Cook. I think now I have a lot of literature to read further. Could you specify the precise literature by Olver you mentioned? And as I said, I've no idea about how to apply Frobenius theorem.

Comment: @Schuchang Zhang Peter Olver's site is http://www.math.umn.edu/~olver/ and I was reading http://www.amazon.com/Equivalence-Invariants-Symmetry-Peter-Olver/dp/0521101042 however, I think, where I actually read about Frobenius and ODEs may have been in the Cartan For Beginners text in particular sections 1.2, 1.3 and 1.9. I think you might also (eventually... from my naive perspective, the cartan for beginners seems easier to start) want to look at http://arxiv.org/abs/math.DG/0207039 there are others around who can give better advice...

Comment: @Schuchang Zhang You might also consider the Exterior Differential Systems text by Bryant, Chern, et. al.  I believe that it is now out of print, but the .pdf is available at the MSRI website (http://library.msri.org/books/Book18/MSRI-v18-Bryant-Chern-et-al.pdf).

Comment: @ShuchangZhang You have to mention that the domain is contractible, otherwise it is not true, e.g $ \frac{xdy-ydx}{x^2+y^2} $ on $ \mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{0\} $. And you have to use homotopy properties of such domains.